# The continuous relationship between $f(x,y)$ and $\varphi(x)=\lim f(x,y)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, continuity

> Assume $\Bbb{D}=\{(x,y):a\leq x \leq b,0 \leq y <y_0\}$ and $f(x,y)$
>   is continuous for variable $x$ in $\Bbb{D}$. and $f(x,y)$ increases
>   monotonically to $\varphi(x)$ when $y \rightarrow y_0$. 
>   $$\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}f(x,y)=\varphi(x)$$
>   Is $\varphi(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$?

I hope $\varphi(x)$ is continuous, and I trying the following method,but failed.$|\varphi(x)-\varphi(x_0)|\leq |f(x,y)-\varphi(x)|+|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|+|f(x_0,y)-\varphi(x_0)|$ this method seems doesn't work, because $\lim f(x,y)=\varphi(x)$ without uniformly for $x\in[a,b]$. Then $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|$ is dependent on $|f(x,y)-\varphi(x)|$.(i.e. the $\delta$ choose for $|x-x_0|$ and the $\delta$ choose for $|y-y_0|$ is dependent).

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x_0-x_1|<\epsilon$ 
$$|\varphi(x_0)-\varphi(x_1)|=\left|\lim_{y\to y_0} f(x_0,y) -\lim_{y\to y_0} f(x_1,y) \right|=
\left|\lim_{y\to y_0} (f(x_0,y)-f(x_1,y) )  \right|\le
\lim_{y\to y_0} \left|f(x_0,y)-f(x_1,y)   \right|\underset{\text{continuity in $x$}}{\le}\lim_{y\to y_0} \delta=\delta
$$
note that the last inequality is still for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{D}$ so valid regardless of the value of $y$ due to continuity of $f$ in $x$.

Thus, the above shows the continuity of $\varphi(x)$ in $[a,b]$ as required.